$\{ x/p\} $ on average
This is a vague question: Lemma 2.2 of Friedlander and Lagarias' "On the distribution in short intervals of integers having no large prime factor" says that $$\sum _{p\leq w}\left (\{ x/p\} -1/2\right )$$ is small, in other words certainly the average value of $\{ x/p\} $ is 1/2. Here $w$ is not too close to $x$. But if $w$ gets close to $x$, the average value may change. For example, a classical result of de la Vallee Poussin says that the average is actually $1-\gamma $.
Is it "usual/normal" that the average behaviour changes? In the (Montgomery-Hooley refinements of the) Barban-Davenport-Halberstam Theorem the average behaviour changes slightly as $Q\rightarrow x$ as well, but there it's maybe not so strange since the progressions are becoming very sparse.
Of course due to the fractional part we'd expect the average behaviour to change when $p$ gets extremely close to $x$, but there's probably a range not covered in the Friedlander/Lagarias result where I guess it's not clear what the average should be, right?
As I say I don't really have a question, just looking for any comments which might help me understand what to expect when dealing with $\{ x/p\} $.

Please tell us what your symbols stand for. What is x ?  What is w ? What values do p take?

x,w denote real numbers. p denotes a prime number.

That belongs in the question, not in a comment.

maybe, buuut i think it's (just about) ok

And you are taking the average over what range of what variable(s)?

p<w for your favourite w<x

In short, there is cancellation in this sum when $w=o(x)$, but not when $w \asymp x$.
The intuition for the transition at $w\asymp x$ is this: the cancellation in $\sum_{p \le w}(\{x/p\}-1/2)$ comes from the fractional parts $\{x/p\}$ being equidistributed in $[0,1)$, which in turn is equivalent to cancellation in $\sum_{p \le w} e(2 \pi i m x/p)$ for each $m$ (Weyl's equidistribution theorem). If $p \asymp x$, the phases in the exponent are $\asymp 1$, they do not oscillate and so cancellation does not occur.

Let me now back this up using the literature. The distribution of $\{x/n\}$ was studied by Saffari and Vaughan in a series of three papers in 1976-1977. Since the distribution of $\{x/p\}$ should enjoy similar properties, I shall focus on $\{x/n\}$, but see A. Shubin's 2016 paper "Fractional parts of the function x/n", especially Theorem 3, for generalizations and variations of the work of Saffari and Vaughan, including the study of $\{x/p\}$.
Let us focus on Saffari and Vaughan's 2nd paper, "On the fractional parts of {x/n} and related sequences. II". Beware, as it uses some notation from the 1st paper, most importantly $$c_{\alpha}(t) :=\mathbf{1}_{\{t\}\in[0,\alpha)}.$$
Let
$$\Theta_{x,y}(\alpha):=y^{-1}\sum_{n \le y} c_{\alpha}(x/n)$$
for $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Theorem 1 in that paper supposes that $1\le y \le x$ and expresses $\Theta_{x,y}(\alpha)$ as a main term $F(\alpha,x/y)\in (0,1)$ plus an error term of $O(x^{\frac{1}{3}}y^{-1}\log x)$, so it gives a meaningful result for $y /( x^{1/3}\log x)\to \infty$.
As indicated by Saffari and Vaughan, it is likely that $\Theta_{x,y}(\alpha)=F(\alpha,x/y)+o(1)$ holds as long as $y \ge x^{\varepsilon}$, but in general one cannot hope for such a result when $y=(\log x)^{O(1)}$, see their Theorem 5.
So, what is this main term $F(\alpha,x/y)$? In Saffari and Vaughn it is defined as
$$F(\alpha,t) = t\sum_{k>t}\bigg(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+\alpha}\bigg) + \mathbf{1}_{(t-\alpha,t] \cap \mathbb{N} \neq \varnothing}(1-t(\lfloor t\rfloor +\alpha)^{-1}).$$
A much more transparent expression is
$$F(\alpha,t) = \int_{0}^{1} c_{\alpha}(t/u)\mathrm{d}u=\int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{c_{\alpha}(v)}{v^2}\mathrm{d}v,$$
which is the probability that $\{t/u\} \in [0,\alpha)$ where $u$ is chosen uniformly at random from $[0,1]$. It is not hard to show (using either expression)  that
$$F(\alpha,t) =\alpha+o(1) \text{ as }t \to \infty,$$
so one has $\Theta_{x,y}(\alpha) \sim \alpha$ as long as $y=o(x)$, at least if $y$ is not too small. It is only when $y \asymp x$ where the behavior starts to change. (What about $y/x \to \infty$? This regime is not interesting, since $c_{\alpha}(x/n) = x/n$ for $n\in (x/\alpha,y]$.)
The quantity $\Theta_{x,y}(\alpha)$ lies quite deep as it relates to the error term in the Dirichlet divisor problem, see equations (1.5) and (1.6) in Saffari-Vaughan.

To give an idea of the proof of Theorem 1, we write
$$\Theta_{x,y}(\alpha) = y^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{\substack{n\le y \\ k\le x/n <k+1} } \mathbf{1}_{x/n-k < \alpha}=y^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{\substack{n\le y \\ k\le x/n <k+\alpha} } 1,$$
where $k$ stands for the value of $\lfloor x/n\rfloor$.
By considering separately $k>x/y$ and $x/y-\alpha < k\le x/y$, one can approximate this using $F(\alpha,x/y)$ and already obtain a weak version of Theorem 1.

thanks a lot! that's great (as always:) )
